# Adding a primary key with an "insert into" statement

Tags: t-sql

I have the following query and need to add a Primary Key to the Column of Employeenumber:

```
SELECT [Exceptions].Employeenumber,[Exceptions].exceptiondate, [Exceptions].starttime, [exceptions].endtime, [Exceptions].code, datediff(minute, starttime, endtime)  as minutes INTO scratchpad3,
FROM Employees INNER JOIN Exceptions ON [Exceptions].EmployeeNumber = [Exceptions].Employeenumber
where [Exceptions].exceptiondate between '5/1/2011' and '5/8/2011'
GROUP BY [Exceptions].Employeenumber, [Exceptions].Exceptiondate, [Exceptions].starttime, [exceptions].endtime,
[Exceptions].code, [Exceptions].exceptiondate
```

but don't know the proper syntax when you're doing a "create" this way. What's the propery syntax to add a primary key this way?

Thank you.

Comment: don't use `<code>` tags here. Highlight the code/query and hit the `{}` button in the editor (or `Control+K`).

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a Primary Key to a SELECT statement. Primary Keys are identifying columns of tables. You'd need to ALTER TABLE and ADD PRIMARY KEY. The syntax is different, but it looks like you're using SQL Server. Statements can be found  [Here.](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-primary-key.html)

If you're looking to just add a number for each record, try using ROW_NUMBER (might be different depending on the database you're using).

Hope that helps,
Jason

Comment: actually jason, I was approaching this from the wrong side. I should have been doing this from the vb.net and not the sql side. thank you for the information though.